# Mediawiki - How do I change which page is the main page?

Tags: mediawiki

I have setup my own Madiawiki for a project. I would like to change the main page but the only thing the Mediawiki FAQ say is:

“By default, MediaWiki looks for a page with the title Main Page and serves this as the default page. This can be changed by altering the contents of MediaWiki:Mainpage to point to a different title. If this does not change the 'Main Page' link included on the sidebar at install time, edit MediaWiki:Sidebar.”

The problem is I do not know where to edit this “MediaWiki:Mainpage”. Where do I find this line to edit it? Also if I make a page with the name “x”, and I want it to be the main page do I then change “MediaWiki:Mainpage” to “MediaWiki:x”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the search bar, type `MediaWiki:Mainpage`. Then edit it so its content is the name of the page you want to be the main page. `MediaWiki:Mainpage` should always contain the title, because it is a system message that is reserved for the title of the main page, so don't change it to `MediaWiki:x`.

See also: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Main_Page for changing the main page and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Namespaces#MediaWiki for the MediaWiki namespace and system messages.